# A difficult integral for the Chern number

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, definite-integrals, characteristic-classes

The integral
$$
I(m)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}y \frac{m\cos(x)\cos(y)-\cos x-\cos y}{\left( \sin^2x+\sin^2y +(m-\cos x-\cos y)^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
gives the Chern number of a certain vector bundle [1] over a torus. It can be shown using the theory of characteristic classes that
$$
I(m) = \frac{\mathrm{sign}(m-2)+\mathrm{sign}(m+2)}{2}-\mathrm{sign}(m) = \begin{cases}1 & -2< m < 0 \\ -1 & 0 < m < 2 \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
Is there any way to evaluate this integral directly (i.e. without making use of methods from differential geometry) to obtain the above result?

I should mention that the above integral can be written as ($1/4\pi$ times) the solid angle subtended from the origin of the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$,
$$
I(m)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\pi}^\pi\mathrm{d}y\, \hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\left(\partial_x \hat{\mathbf{n}}\times \partial_y \hat{\mathbf{n}}\right),
$$
where $\mathbf{n}(m)=(\sin x, \sin y, m- \cos x-\cos y)$. While this form makes it very straightforward to evaluate $I(m)$, I am interested in whether there is a way to compute this integral using more standard techniques.

---

[1] B. Bernevig *Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors* Chapter 8

Comment: It appears there are two cases missing: $I(\pm2)=\mp1/2$.

Comment: The case $m=0$ is easy because we can rewrite as $-\pi I(0)=\int_0^\pi f(x)\,dx$ where $$f(x)=\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos x+\cos y}{(2+2\cos x\cos y)^{3/2}}\,dy$$ and we find that $f(x)=-f(\pi-x)$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$ after substituting $u=\pi-y$. So $I(0)=0$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire do you know$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} 
\frac{\text{d}x\text{d}y}{\sqrt{\sin(x)^2+\sin(y)^2+\left ( 1-\cos(x)-\cos(y) \right )^2 } 
}=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{8\pi}?$$

Comment: @SetnessRamesory That case can probably be done with elliptic integrals but I still believe there must be an easier way to prove $I(m)=0\quad\forall|m|>2$, for instance. Due to the symmetry of the integrand and the exponent of $3/2$, an application of Green's theorem may be useful, similar to [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910817/471884).

Comment: @xzd209 I would suggest you crosspost this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net), ensuring the post includes a link to this MathStackExchange post.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire done :) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453343/a-difficult-integral-for-the-chern-number